# piano note sheet missunderstanding

Tags: chords

I am new to world of music, so my question is beginner-like one. Here is excerpt from some note-sheet:

[image: Piano notes]

My understanding regarding for example first F chord is that left hand should play note A as well as right hand. Then how F chord (or maybe some inversion) has to be played ? There are more similar questions related to this note sheet.

Comment: Thanks for link - very similar question, although I must rethink the answers presented there.

Comment: Where is the picture from? What is someone trying to explain with that notation? Is it a song? An exercise? What is it supposed to represent?

Comment: It is from pdf file, I downloaded earlier. It's name is "Jumbo easy piano songbook". Very first song - named "Abide with me" and I noticed no further comment there regarding this song.

Comment: Ok, so this is an intro to Abide with me. I think the linked question explains the relationship between the notes and the chord symbols. Don't forget to buy the PDFs you download! https://www.amazon.com/Jumbo-Easy-Piano-Songbook-Occasions/dp/0634062883

Answer (score 2):

Without explanation it's unclear if this a piece to be played as written or if you're expected to fill in the missing harmonies.
If you add harmonies, the first F chord must be a first inversion because A is in the bass, but it's missing F and C, so you need to add either or both of them. There are two of each in the two octaves between bass and melody. The lower C probably won't sound good because it's too close to the bass which leaves you with middle C. Add either of the two F possibilities and you have a complete chord.
Same for the next chord C7 which has be second inversion because G is in the bass.

Playing the notes as written is probably the best way to start learning this.

Comment: Sorry for I cannot add reputation to your quote, due to my beginner status in this forum.

Answer (score 0):

The chord symbols on top are for a guitarist in particular to play. They reflect the harmony of the piece at each point. A good pianist would also be capable of 'filling in' extra noes, especially the 'missing' notes. They're not actually missing, though. The treble and bass clef work fine as they stand.

On that 1st F chord - the notes played are both A, as you say. That's the way the writer wanted it. That A note would fit an F chord better than the preceding C chord, which is why F is written there. Although Csus would work as well. After F, the next note (last in bar) needs a C harmony - C7 precisely - as it's the dominant chord of the following F.

Whatever inversion a guitarist would play is up to them. I guess the most appropriate might be the one which reflects the music most accurately - F/A.

Comment: Gm works just as well as C7 on the fourth quarter of the first bar (in fact I prefer it).

Comment: @PiedPiper - so does Bb, Bb6, Bbm, Gm7, F#7, Eb9...

Comment: Yes, but your answer says the note ""needs a C harmony". It doesn't.

Comment: @PiedPiper - Got me! I said that in a nod towards the existing sheet, provided by OP.  As written, the next F could need that C harmony to lead to it. I tried to keep it at the basic level that the sheet showed. Sticking with C harmony, C7b9 works nicely. Just had a few minutes re-harmonising the whole thing! Great fun.